# how to get a real fliped linearScale in D3 barchart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm new in D3js and a I don't understand how work the `scaleLinear()` function to convert data into "pixel".

Since the svg is drawn from top to bottom and I want my axis to be drawn from bottom to top, I set the parameters in `range()` as `range([max, min])` to flip the axis.

Then, I thought that the 1st value of the table in `domain()` will correspond to the 1st value of the table in `range()`:

```js
const yAxisScale = d3
      .scaleLinear()
      .range([max, min])
//             ↑    ↑
      .domain([min, max])
```

However, it seems that the minimum value of the `domain()` parameter is set to the min value of the `range()`, and max of `domain()` to max of `range()`, no matter the order of the values in the tables.

Given the example at the bottom of this post, when I use the scale to set the height of the bar with `.attr("height", data => yAxisScale(data.y))`, I was expecting the 1st bar to be 100 according to dataset, but it actually renders 400.

So if I want to correctly display the data, I have to set the "y" as `yAxisScale(data.y)` and "height" as `chartHeight - yAxisScale(data.y)`. It's not very intuitive for me, I mean the height should be directly proportionnal to the input data.

**So is there a way to enhance my scale definition in order to have my `yAxisScale()` fonction working as I thought it would ?**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>bar chart issue</title>
    <style>
        #root {border:  1px solid black}
    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <svg id="root"></svg>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3@7"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    dataset = [
        {x:1, y: 100},
        {x:2, y: 400},
        {x:3, y: 200},
        {x:4, y: 300},
        {x:5, y: 500},
    ]

    const svgWidth = 600;
    const svgHeight = 400;
    const margin = { top: 50, bottom: 50, left: 20, right: 80 };
    const chartWidth = svgWidth - margin.left - margin.right; // =500
    const chartHeight = svgHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom; // =300

/* root svg */
    const svg = d3
      .select("#root")
      .attr("width", svgWidth)
      .attr("height", svgHeight);


/* chart */
    const chart = svg
      .append('g')
      .attr('class', 'chart')
      .attr('width', chartWidth)
      .attr('height', chartHeight)
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');


/* X axis */
    const xAxisScale = d3
      .scaleLinear()
      .range([0, chartWidth])
      .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, (data) => data.x) + 1]);

    chart.append('g')
      .attr('class', 'xAxis')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + chartHeight + ')')
      .call(d3.axisBottom(xAxisScale).tickValues(dataset.map((data) => data.x)))
      .selectAll('text')
      .style('text-anchor', 'middle');;


/* Y axis */
    const yAxisScale = d3
      .scaleLinear()
      .range([chartHeight, 0])
      .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, (data) => data.y)]);

    chart.append('g')
      .attr('class', 'yAxis')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + chartWidth + ', 0)')
      .call(d3.axisRight(yAxisScale).ticks(6));


/* Bars */
    chart.append('g')
      .attr('class', 'bars')
      .selectAll('rect')
      .data(dataset)
      .enter()
      .append('rect')
      .attr("fill", "darkRed")
      .attr("x", data => xAxisScale(data.x)-5)
      .attr("width", 10)
      .attr("y", data => chartHeight - yAxisScale(data.y))
      .attr("height", data => yAxisScale(data.y))

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

preview:
[preview of the rendered bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jgo41.png)

Answer (score 1):

SVG's y axis direction is what you need to look at here.

Positive y is downwards, instead of upwards.
Anchor point is top left, whereas in normal math you'd assume it is is bottom left.

Therefore you need the scaling function to reverse the direction. So you need 0 to be at {height - marginBottom} and max to be at {marginTop}.

Now, For a bar chart, there is another complication. In normal math, you'd assume -> go to x, go to y(0) and draw a rect of height yAxisScale(d.y). In SVG however, height is downwards. It is go to x, go to chartHeight- yAxisScale(d.y). Draw a rect of height yAxisScale(d.y).

So to achieve this, you need to set height to chartHeight - yaxisScale(d.y)

```
    const yAxisScale = d3
      .scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, d=>d.y)])
      .range([chartHeight, 0])
```

See JSFiddle here

https://jsfiddle.net/6khb7rLu/9/

Comment: Hi and thanks for the response. I agree with your method to define `height=AxisScale(data.y)` as a more convenient way. But as seen on your JSFiddle, the y-axis is now from top to bottom and the height of the bars do not correspond to the scale on the axis (1st data point is 100 but the scale shows 400).
All example I've seen so far are using `height = chartHeight - yAxisScale(data.y)` so I guess it's the way it has to be done ^^'

Comment: sorry.. that was an oversight.. Have fixed it in the fiddle now..